# centering a div

Tags: css

I am trying to center a div but due to it being a block and general text or image being inline it does not work...The stuff inside the div gets centered but not the div itself...How can I do this? Ive tried a bunch of things from Google but I couldn't get it to work...

http://dev.icalapp.rogersdigitalmedia.com.rogers-test.com/menutest.htm

the code of interest is below:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var mygallery=new fadeSlideShow({
    wrapperid: "fadeshow1", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
    dimensions: [500, 360], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of largest image
    imagearray: [
        ["01.jpg"],
        ["02.jpg"],
        ["03.jpg"],
        ["04.jpg"] //<--no trailing comma after very last image element!
    ],
    displaymode: {type:'auto', pause:2500, cycles:0, wraparound:false},
    persist: false, 
    fadeduration: 500, //transition duration (milliseconds)
    descreveal: "ondemand",
    togglerid: ""
})




</script>

</head>

<body>
<div  id="fadeshow1"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of numerous other SO questions.  See links along right column of this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in css

```
#fadeshow1{

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: THE WIDTH OF THE DIV
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! I have spent many hours and this worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you center divs, with CSS:

```
#fadeshow1 { margin:0 auto; }
```

Comment: Yes, and make sure you have a width. If it's 100% of the parent div, it won't be centered.

Answer (score 1):

1. The div has to have a width specified.
2. You need to add the styles `margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;`