# Cross Browser Center

Tags: html, css

I have an element which is an image within a div id. I am going to make this page a under construction page. I made the div with a "margin: auto" css command. What is away vertically that I can have the div auto center to any browser accessed by the site?

New to this don't know how to do the whole JSFiddle thing lol

Heres a url too: http://nerissagrigsby.com/?page_id=5

My CSS:

```
#openpagesig {
width: 803px;
height: 283px;
margin: auto;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="openpagesig">
    <img src="img/LoginSignature.png" width="803" height="283" alt="Login Signature"
    />
</div>
<!-- Open Page Signature -->
</body>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [centering a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668632/centering-a-div)

Comment: @Diodeus - Not that one but a search shows 114 SO pages with the topic 'vertical center element'.

Comment: MY BAD MAN TAKE IT EASY ON ME! I suck at research

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the following CSS:

```
.inTheMiddle { /* or "#myImageId" (or just "img" if it's the only one) */
    position: absolute; /* or "fixed" */

    /* The element you want to place in the middle of the page
       center should have explicitly defined dimensions: */
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px; /* offset back at exactly half height of the element */
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px; /* offset back at exactly half width of the element */
}
```

Here's [a working example](http://jsbin.com/usuren/1/edit).

Do I need to mention, that **this works even in Internet Explorer 5.5!** ... but I doubt this browser is still relevant to anyone.

Please refer to the image below to see how the negative margins help:

[image: How negative margins work to offset an element]

Comment: Hey man, I think I'm going to go along with this solution. With the "position: absolute" and "top: 50%" why do you use the "margin-top: -50px;"

Comment: When you place an element with `top:50%; left:50%;` the **element's top-left corner** is in the middle of the page, so we need to push the entire element back by half width and half height so that **its center is in the middle**. Of course you can provide your own dimensions to the element, just don't forget to divide them by 2 when offsetting back.

Comment: So did you mean to say "Margin-top: -50px;" As apose to Margin-top: -50%"?

Comment: This solution has a major disadvantage, if your browser window is smaller than the height of your content it will hide the content, and you can't scroll to see it. Check out this solution / my answer: http://jsbin.com/owayec/2/ then resize the page and see how it reacts.

Comment: @HerbertPeters The negative margin must be in pixels (`em` will probably work too by the way), because the percent will refer to the percentage of width of the window and not the element.

Comment: @Seer Your solution is okay, but I *personally* wouldn't recommend it because it is: 1) overly complex, 2) requires modifications in the HTML structure, 3) doesn't center when window's width is less than the element's width, 4) doesn't seem to work across all browsers which is an OP's requirement.

Comment: The problem with Oleg's solution is you must change the CSS to manually set your `margin` to exactly half the width of the image if the content is ever updated. The solution I posted is similar to Seer's solution, except doesn't require modification of the html element, I used a `fixed` position div as the container. Regardless, all three solutions are sound and the one Mr. Peters selects should most adequately suit his project's needs.

Comment: @Joey Agreed on manually setting the margin. However, my approach does not require any special container (altering HTML for styling is considered bad practice) and works out of the box even on long-forgotten browsers. `display: table;` is not supported in IE<8: http://caniuse.com/css-table

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I misread two things, I thought you meant altering the HTML tag itself with CSS, and when I checked http://caniuse.com/#search=css-table and didn't notice IE<8 was missing from the list :P. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
.centeredDiv {
    width:17em;
    height:9em;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-135px 0 0 -155px;
    padding:1em;
    background-color:#fffff7;
    opacity:0.67;
    filter:alpha(opacity=67); /* for IE8 and earlier */
    border:2px solid #191919;
}
```

Obviously editing measurements and colours to suit.

Comment: Whats the perks of using "em" as apose "px, %"

Comment: `em` is a typographic unit of measurement (based on the width on the letter 'm' in whatever font you're using). I like them because any elements styled with them scale along with the text. `px` are pixels and so don't scale at all. `%` also scale and there's good article on [A list apart](http://alistapart.com/article/howtosizetextincss) about the relative merits of `em` and `%`.

Comment: I'd recommend using just pixels in this particular case because we are dealing with an image which has pixel-based dimensions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-content">
            <div class="content">
              <img src="//placehold.it/803x283" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>


<style>

  html, body {
    height: 100%;
  }

  .container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
  }

  .container-content {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .container-content > .content {
    max-width: 803px;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

</style>
```

This solution works very nicely, because not only does it vertically center the content, but if the browser windows height is too small to display it all, you can still scroll to see all of the content which is one of the major drawbacks of using other methods.

Example:

http://jsbin.com/owayec/2/

Comment: Actually, I like this solution man goooooodd stuff. But what would be your fix for Ie 7.0, 8.0, 9.0 view your solution in those browsers. The element just sits to the top left.

Comment: Also with this: ".container-content > .content" Why did you use the ">" in the CSS coding? Is that consider like a CSS3 thing?

Comment: It's not necessary, but it's handy. That selects elements that are direct children to the parent element, here is the fix for IE, I've tested it in IE8 and IE9: http://jsbin.com/owayec/3/

Comment: The placeholder in the third revision stays in the top left corner of the window when viewing the site in IE6. I do agree though that IE6 is almost dead anyway... Still, if you go as far as setting `display: table;` and adding a number of container `div`s, why don't you simply use a `table`?

Comment: Indeed, IE6 is dead, thankfully! I use `div`'s because it is more semantically correct and also the markup is a lot simpler if you just style it with `display: table;` you don't need `<table><tbody><tr><td> ...` and you don't have to mess around with the rest of the styles that come with it being a table... XD

Comment: Well... you're against `<table><tbody><tr><td>...` (`tbody` not needed by the way as it will be created anyway), but okay with `<div class="container"><div class="container-content"><div class="content">...`? Are you sure about that? :)

Comment: Consider that you would still need extra styles applied to the table and the td elements (i.e. classes), so, it would still be more markup needed to use the tables. The divs allow you to be more flexible, for example if you had other styles for responsive designs, you wouldn't need to be picking apart the styles of a table, you'd just need to alter the styles of a div, which is a simple block element. It has it's advantages.

Comment: Ok Thanks Seer, The last updated code with the Ie 8,9 fix still throws an error in 7. It centers but not vertically. What do I do in a situation where the person your coding for has an Ie 7 version running and is weird because the site is messed up in their browser? Is there a fix for Ie7? How do you go about coding for all browsers and finding your Ie fixes?

Comment: You could then use the if conditionals in your HTML to apply different styles to the page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is related to vertically aligning `div` elements on a page. This is a common problem in HTML and CSS coding.

One solution is to have a container element within an outer `div` tag. The outer `div` should be set to `display: table;` and `position: fixed;` with 100% `width` and `height` as well. Set the inner `div` to `display: table-cell;` with the `vertical-align: middle;` property.

Furthermore, the outer `div` should have `text-align: center;` in order to center its child elements.

Here is the code you need:

```
.outer { 
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
}
.container {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

An example from jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/otolot/1/

Try resizing the window to see that this works.